# Tensorflow CNN: Accessing the data from the Convolution layer to be used in the Lambda layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I'm working on creating a Lambda layer after the Convolution Layer using Tensorflow 2.x.
I have a function named "custom_layer" which takes in the tensor output from the previous convolution layer.
I need to extract each feature maps of the convolution layer from this tensor and perform mathematical operations.
Finally, the outputs have to be combined into a single tensor and returned to be used in the next layer.

```
#Lamba layer
def custom_layer(tensor):
    # perform operation on individual feature maps


    # return the combined tensor output
    return tensor
```

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters= 64, kernel_size= (3,3), input_shape = (28,28,1), activation = 'relu', name = 'conv2D_1'),

    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(custom_layer, name="lambda_layer"),

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters= 64, kernel_size= (3,3), activation = 'relu', name = 'conv2D_2'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), name = 'MaxPool2D_1'),      
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation= 'softmax')])
```

Using `tf.print(tensor)` I was able to view the tensor output (feature maps). But I'm not able to figure out a method to access those individual feature maps.

Comment: for example, which kind of operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved. I used tf.py_function() within the custom_layer(tensor) function.

Comment: Dear sir, would you please share your answer to this issue. i am new to tensorflow and keras and i am searching for the solution to this issue since a couple months ago. please you would save my life. you are the only hope..